# Passing a local variable to :file render method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, render

I'm having an issue passing a variable to a builder file for xml generation, and think I might be approaching the problem completely wrong, but here is my current attempt:

```
<% @x = [1000, 2000, 3000] %>
<%str_xml = render :file=>"filepath/file", :locals=>{:x => x} %>
```

And then inside of the file.builder I try to access x, but keep getting

```
undefined local variable or method `x'
```

Where I try to access it in the builder as

```
xml.dataset(:seriesName => 'Bogus') do
  for element in x 
    xml.set(:value=>element)
  end
end
```

The code works fine as long as I don't try to access the x variable. Eventually the x will become two dates that will be converted to timestamps, and passed to the xml builder to be used in the database queries to determine to the time range of data to display. I'm very green with rails, so am completely open to the idea that I'm approaching the idea backwards. Any and all help are appreciated!

Thank You

Comment: Still getting the same error, although if I remove the @ on the declaration of x( '<% @x=' goes to '<% x=') I get a 'You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!' error message, which I think is a step in the right direction since it as at least recognizing there is an object called x being passed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Devin commented 'x' should be '@x'. I'd also recommend not setting variables in the view, try to have variables used to display data set in the corresponding method of the controller (and as much as possible have any actions that change data be part of the model).

```
# app/controllers/my_controller.rb

class MyController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @x = [Date.new(2010, 8, 5).to_time.to_i, DateTime.new(2011, 8, 5).to_time.to_i]
  end
end

# app/views/my/index.erb

<%str_xml = render :file=>"filepath/file", :locals=>{:x => @x} %>
```

Comment: Accepting this as the answer, with credit to Devin M and one caveat: I also needed to change the 'for element in x' to 'for element in @x'. Thanks for the help :) As a followup, how would you recommend getting the timestamps to display if not setting them as a local variable?

Comment: Updated my answer to show var set in controller, any instance var (starting with '@') set in the index method will be available in the corresponding view